# a redrawing of a view is not smooth [Android]

Tags: android, user-interface, view, visibility

I have a small button, and i'm setting it to View.GONE for some parts and back. When i call setVisibility(), I see it draws the button sometimes in two phases, not smooth.
I have a condition to check what is the visibility and how to change it (GONE,VISIBLE) and after the condition, i call the invalidate() and then requestLayout().
How can i fix it so it will change smoothly?

Thank You.

Comment: why do you call invalidate() and equestLayout()? it should work without it.

Comment: Didn't change anything. This is a remainder from older bugs.

Comment: on what device do you debug? is there another heavy activity that happens on your UI constantly?